# Redefined symfony root project

Tags: symfony, capifony

I took over a project with a file structure similar to this:

```
Project /
     conf /
     symfony /
         app /
         src /
         ...
     scripts
     other folders ...
```

I am interested in capifony recently and I tried to set up capifony with this file structure but it does not work because when deployed capifony seeks symfony files in `./Web` `./App` etc ...

Before changing the file structure, I would like to know if there is a way to tell capifony the root of symfony is in `./Symfony` instead of `./` ?

I tried to redefine `app_path` and `web_path` in `deploy.rb` file, but it does not seem enough.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your root project directory (assuming you haven't capified your project yet):

```
capifony -s 2 -p symfony/app .
```

Comment: hello, thank you very much for the reply, unfortunately it does not solve the my problem.

during deployment, capifony trying to create a symbolic link to `/releases/20121002193555/web/uploads` (which does not exists) instead of `/releases/20121002193555/symfony/web/uploads`

same for vendors `/releases/20121002193555/vendor` instead of `/releases/20121002193555/symfony/vendor`

I searched myself, I have not found a way to configure this possibility in the file deploy.rb. thank you for helping

Comment: In that case I'd say that there's a bug in capifony. If you're able to fix it send a PR, if not, report a bug on github: https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues